# Подсчет в столбце MySQL

Tags: mysql

Имеется Join запрос и необходимо соответственно `'SELECT * FROM`authors`INNER JOIN`books`USING (id_author) SUM("quantity")` для автора из одной таблицы подсчитать кол-во книг на складе из другой таблицы. Т.е. посчитать значения 1 столбца. (Столбец quantity)

В первой таблице автор . Во второй книги. И мне нужно вывести фамилию - кол-во книг

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не ясно что такое подсичтать столбец. считать можно строки, если добавить group by по id автора, то count(*) как раз даст количество записей для автора. если же вам нужна сумма значений столбца то вместо count надо использовать sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое интересное в таких задачах - а для чего именно Вам первая таблица? Если я всё правильно понял, то Вам нужно:

```
SELECT `id_author`, SUM(`quantity`) FROM `books` GROUP BY `id_author`
```

Если всё же по какой-то причине Вам требуется что-то из таблицы `authors`, то тогда так, например:

```
SELECT `a`.`name`, SUM(`b`.`quantity`)
FROM `authors` `a`
INNER JOIN `books` `b` USING `id_author`
GROUP BY `a`.`id_author`
```

Либо если нужно вывести с учетом того, что у автора может не быть книг:

```
SELECT `a`.`name`, COALESCE(SUM(`b`.`quantity`),0)
FROM  `authors` `a`
LEFT JOIN `books` `b` USING `id_author`
GROUP BY `a`.`id_author`
```

Comment: В первой таблице автор. Во второй книги. И мне нужно вывести фамилию - кол-во книг

Comment: @RedScreed, я полагаю, это должен был в задаче написать я?) или каждый читающий должен догадываться?)

Comment: у меня просто подсчет не работал, думал есть какой-либо другой способ)

Comment: @RedScreed, добавил два варианта согласно изменению. Либо так, либо еще что-то недоговариваете.

Comment: Запрос ошибку выдаёт, хотя по структуре все верно для моей БД.

Comment: Ошибка, похоже в части  `SUM(`b`.`quantity`)`

Comment: Добавил структуру таблицы

Comment: @RedScreed, ошибка была в части GROUP - забыл прописать из какой таблицы поле брать.